# Python separating class and main program into different files

Tags: python, class

I am learning object oriented programming techniques in Python. Having created a vector class which is becoming increasingly longer and more complicated, I would like to separate my class from the main program by creating a separate file. The class can subsequently be imported into the main program as and when it is needed.

Here is the file `vector_class.py` containing the class vector

```
class vector(object):

    def __init__(self, x=None, y=None, z=None, angle=None):

        if angle == None:
            self.x, self.y, self.z = x, y, z
        if angle != None:
            if angle == "rad":
                self.r, self.theta, self.phi = x, y, z
            if angle == "deg":
                self.r = x
                self.theta = y * 2. * pi / 360.
                self.phi = z * 2. * pi / 360.
            self.x = self.r * sin(self.theta) * cos(self.phi)
            self.y = self.r * sin(self.theta) * sin(self.phi)
            self.z = self.r * cos(self.theta)

    def show(self):
        print "[", self.x, "\t", self.y, "\t", self.z, "]"

    def write(self):
        file.write("[" + str(self.x) + ",\t" + str(self.y) + ",\t" + str(self.z) + "]")
    def write_sph(self):
        file.write("[" + str(self.mag()) + ",\t" + str(self.gettheta()) + ",\t" + str(self.getphi()) + "]")
    def swrite(self):
        file.write(str(self.x) + "\t" + str(self.y) + "\t" + str(self.z))
    def swrite_sph(self):
        file.write(str(self.mag()) + "\t" + str(self.gettheta()) + "\t" + str(self.getphi()))

    def getx(self):
        return self.x
    def gety(self):
        return self.y
    def getz(self):
        return self.z

    def setx(self, x):
        self.x = x
    def sety(self, y):
        self.y = y
    def setz(self, z):
        self.z = z

    def square(self):
        return self.x*self.x + self.y*self.y + self.z*self.z
    def mag(self):
        return sqrt(self.square())

    def gettheta(self):
        return arccos(self.z / self.mag())
    def getphi(self):
        return arctan2(self.y, self.x) # sign depends on which quadrant the coordinates are in

    def add(self, v):
        v_sum = vector(self.getx() + v.getx(), self.gety() + v.gety(), self.getz() + v.getz())
        return v_sum
    def minus(self, v):
        v_minus = vector(self.getx() - v.getx(), self.gety() - v.gety(), self.getz() - v.getz())
        return v_minus
    def diff(self, v):
        v_diff = vector(abs(self.getx() - v.getx()), abs(self.gety() - v.gety()), abs(self.getz() - v.getz()))
        return v_diff
    def inc(self, const): 
        v_new = vector(self.getx() + const, self.gety() + const, self.getz() + const)
        return v_new
    def times(self, const):
        v_new = vector(self.getx() * const, self.gety() * const, self.getz() * const)
        return v_new
    def div(self, const):
        v_new = vector(self.getx() / const, self.gety() / const, self.getz() / const)
        return v_new
    def sprod(self, v):
        ans = self.getx() * v.getx() + self.gety() * v.gety() + self.getz() * v.getz()
        return ans
    def vprod(self, v):
        v_new = vector()
        v_new.setx(self.gety() * v.getz() - self.getz() * v.gety())
        v_new.sety(self.getz() * v.getx() - self.getx() * v.getz())
        v_new.setz(self.getx() * v.gety() - self.gety() * v.getx())
        return v_new
```

Here is the file `section2.py` containing the main program which imports the class vector

```
from numpy import *
from vector_class import vector

v0 = vector(0., 0., 0.)
v1 = vector(-1.3054, 7.4033, 2.7362)
v2 = vector(8., 70., 100., "deg")
v3 = vector(8., 1.2217, 1.7453, "rad")

file = open("tasks.txt", 'w')

file.write("task 1 : method to print to file \n\n")
file.write("v0 = ")
v0.write()
file.write("\nv1 = ")
v1.write()

file.write("\n\ntask 2 : spherical polar constructor \n\n")
file.write("v2 = ")
v2.write()
file.write("\nv3 = ")
v3.write()

file.write("\n\ntask 3 : accessing individual coordinates \n\n")
file.write("v1 x component = " + str(v1.getx()) + "\n")
file.write("v1 y component = " + str(v1.gety()) + "\n")
file.write("v1 z component = " + str(v1.getz()) + "\n")

file.write("\ntask 4 : square and magnitude of the three vector \n\n")
file.write("v1 squared = " + str(v1.square()) + "\n")
file.write("v1 magnitude = " + str(v1.mag()) + "\n")

file.write("\ntask 5 : calculating spherical polar angles \n\n")
file.write("v1 spherical = ")
v1.write_sph()
file.write("\nv2 spherical = ")
v2.write_sph()
file.write("\nv3 spherical = ")
v3.write_sph()

file.write("\n\ntask 6 : modifying individual coordinates \n\n")
file.write("v0 = ")
v0.write()
v0.setx(7.77), v0.sety(8.88), v0.setz(9.99)
file.write("\nv0 = ")
v0.write()

file.write("\n\ntask 7 : adding vectors the hard way\n\n")
v4 = vector()
file.write("v0 + v1 = ")
v4.setx(v0.getx() + v1.getx())
v4.sety(v0.gety() + v1.gety())
v4.setz(v0.getz() + v1.getz())
v4.write()

file.write("\n\ntask 8 : overloading the add operator\n\n")
v4 = v0.add(v1)
file.write("v0 + v1 = ")
v4.write()

file.write("\n\ntask 9 : overloading the minus and increment operators \n\n")
v5 = v0.minus(v1)
file.write("v0 - v1 = ")
v5.write()
v6 = v0.inc(3.)
file.write("\nv0 += 3. = ")
v6.write()

file.write("\n\ntask 10 : scaling a vector \n\n")
v7 = v0.times(2.)
file.write("v0 * 2 = ")
v7.write()
v8 = v0.div(2.)
file.write("\nv0 / 2 = ")
v8.write()

file.write("\n\ntask 11 : the scalar product \n\n")
file.write("v0 . v1 = " + str(v0.sprod(v1)))

file.write("\n\ntask 12 : the vector product \n\n")
v9 = v0.vprod(v1)
file.write("v0 x v1 = ")
v9.write()

file.write("\n\ntask13 : triple product test \n\n")
file.write("v0 . (v0 x v1) = " + str(v0.sprod(v0.vprod(v1))))

file.close()
exit()
```

When I run the main program I get the error `TypeError: descriptor 'write' requires a 'file' object but received a 'str'`, but if all of the code is in one file everything works fine. Why am I getting the error and how do I go about getting things working with two separate files for the class and main program?

Comment: What line is the error coming from?

Comment: do you have the files in the same directory?

Comment: yes, the files are saved in the same directory

Comment: the error is on line 13 in the main program

Answer (score 1):

`file` is a [built-in name](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#file), so naming a variable `file` might break some things. `file` isn't defined in vector.py, so you're calling the [`write()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.write) function of file objects, but you're calling it as a static function, so it isn't working. I agree with @roippi about adding a file object as a parameter of `vector`'s constructor:

```
def __init__(self, f, x=None, y=None, z=None, angle=None)
```

I renamed it `f` here to avoid the first problem I mentioned, but you can call it something else. You just need to do a find and replace now, replacing "file" with "f" in vector.py.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but to solve the problem the class vector needs a parameter which specifies the file that the write method writes to. If I apply the changes you suggested, namely introducing the parameter `f` into the constructor and replacing "file" with "f" in vector_class.py, I get the error: global name 'f' is not defined. Does the constructor need some sort of statement such as self.f = file?

Comment: @ZootWarren Yeah, that's exactly right. I forgot about that part.

Comment: Haven't got this working yet. I've replaced the variable `file` with `f` in both section2.py and vector_class.py. The constructor is now `def __init__(self, f=None, x=None, y=None, z=None, angle=None):` and includes the statement `if f == None: self.f = f` so the default text file becomes `f` (therefore no need to alter my instances). I'm getting the same error as before. Any thoughts?

Comment: You need to refer to it with `self.f`, not just `f`.

Comment: Yep changed that too. Now I get AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'

Comment: @ZootWarren Yeah, the default value for `f` is `None`. You can't write to that object. I don't see a reason to have a default value for `f`.

Comment: Also, that `if` statement will just set `self.f` to `None` if `f` is `None`. I'm not sure what you mean by "no need to alter [your] instances.

Comment: The default is an attempt to simplify things. So if I wanted to create a default vector I would simply write `vector()`, as opposed to explicitly writing out the arguments like `vector(f, 0., 0., 0., cartesian)`.

Comment: If you simply write `vector()`, like you seem to be doing, then it *won't work*. `None` does *not have* a `write()` function.

Comment: So I need to update every instance to include the extra argument for the file? There's a lot of them :(

Comment: @ZootWarren A find/replace shouldn't be hard, but if you want a module to have access to an object, then you have to give it to it somehow. Another way I just thought of is just setting `vector.f=f` when you import the module somewhere. Then, you could use it with `vector.f` in that file.

Answer (score 0):

```
def write(self):
    file.write("[" + str(self.x) + ",\t" + str(self.y) + ",\t" + str(self.z) + "]")
```

You are referring to a global, `file`, within the body of this method.  Globals are global **per module**, not across an interpreter instance.  Thus when things are in separate modules, python does not know how to resolve this global name lookup.

I suggest rewriting your `vector` constructor to receive a file handle (or a string pointing to a file) and storing that in an instance variable.

Comment: One example is to receive the file handler in your `__init__` then set `self.file` to the file handler. Then, use `self.file` instead of `file` for the rest of the code in your module.